Gradle: How to share build logic between subprojects?
I am a native Maven user and Gradle is new territory for me. I'm trying to build a multi-module project around a Spring application.
Now I am facing the following problems:

i want Kotlin (plugins and libs) to be present in all projects. The Java version settings and co. should also apply to all projects.

i would like to have a centralized dependency management? I am already stuck here with Version Catalogs.


I had already tried convention plugins via a “buildSrc” project, but I can't access my versions from the Version Catalog in this project?
So how do I configure my project correctly so that I can reuse some parts of the Gradle configuration?

In the root build.gradle.kts you can have an allprojects { ... } block. What you have inside the block will be common things (dependencies etc.) that are applied to all the projects.

Which is highly discouraged bad-practice. Never use allprojects { ... } or similar means to do cross-project configuration.

Yes, that's why I don't want to use the “allprojects” block if possible. It is also not recommended in the Gradle documentation. I've already had bad experiences with it in the past because I didn't know where the configuration of a sub-project came from.

Thanks, I didn't know Gradle didn't recommend allprojects. For reference for future readers, this is stated at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins_vs_cross_configuration

Within Kotlin DSL precompiled script plugins you indeed cannot use the version catalog entries via libs... easily.
There is a hack-around I documented at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15383#issuecomment-779893192 which you could use to make it work.
Alternatively, you could use the string-y API to access the version catalog entries like implementation(versionCatalogs.named("libs").findLibrary("commons-text").orElseThrow(::AssertionError)) or similar.
